# JS to perform calculation based on user input

Tags: javascript

I have a code where I am trying to calculate a total value based on the value of the input selected by a user. It seems simple but I can't get the total to reflect. Please can someone show me where the fault is?

```js
function calculate() {
  var panel = parseInt(document.getElementsById("panel").value);
  panelv = 65;
  panelt = panel * panelv;
  derating_value = 2;
  total_hours_standby = panelt * derating_value;
}

document.getElementsById("total_hours").innerHTML = total_hours_standby;
```

```html
<input type="number" id="panel" placeholder="panel quantity"></input><br>
<button type="button" onclick="calculate">Result</button>

<p id="total_hours">result displays here</p>
```

Comment: shouldn't `document.getElementsById("total_hours").innerHTML = total_hours_standby;` be inside `calculate`

Comment: The `innerHTML` update is outside the function. So it runs once when the script is parsed, and never again.

Comment: I made you a snippet. IMMEDIATELY it tells you one of the problems

Comment: According jsfiddle and browser console there a lot of errors. Two addational hints: replace `ònClick="calculate"`by `onClick="calculate()"` and remove `</input>`

Answer (score 3):

You need to

- use for `onclick="calculate()"` take the function call, not only the function,
- use `getElementById`, spelling matter,
- declare all variables,
- and finally move the output inside of the function

```js
function calculate() {
    var panel = parseInt(document.getElementById("panel").value),
        panelv = 65,
        panelt = panel * panelv,
        derating_value = 2,
        total_hours_standby = panelt * derating_value;

    document.getElementById("total_hours").innerHTML = total_hours_standby;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="panel" placeholder="panel quantity"></input><br>
<button type="button" onclick="calculate()">Result</button>

<p id="total_hours">result displays here</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. getElementById is singular
2. declare your vars
3. call calculate() with brackets
4. assign the value inside the function
5. `</input>` is not needed

Here is a version with eventListeners since other answers already showed you how to fix YOUR version

```js
function calculate() {
  var panel = +document.getElementById("panel").value;
  if (panel === "" || isNaN(panel)) panel = 0;
  let panelv = 65;
  let panelt = panel * panelv;
  let derating_value = 2;
  document.getElementById("total_hours").textContent = (panelt * derating_value);
}
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("calc").addEventListener("click", calculate)
  calculate(); // run at load
})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="panel" placeholder="panel quantity"><br>
<button type="button" id="calc">Result</button> result displays here: <span id="total_hours"></span>
```

Comment: just testing handclaps ... money would be better ...

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues here:

Most you could have found out if you had looked into console logs. 
For starter the function is called getElementById not getElementsById, because there is supposed to be only one element with unique id, so plural does not make sense here.

Another one is a logic error: not updating content after clicking on button i.e when `calculate` gets executed.

There is also one more syntax error, which is how functions should be passed to HTML element's attribute. It needs to be `functionName()` instead of `functionName`

This is how simply fixing this code could look like:

```js
var total_hours_standby = 0;
 function calculate() {
 var panel = parseInt(document.getElementById("panel").value);
 panelv = 65;
 panelt = panel * panelv;
 derating_value = 2;
 total_hours_standby = panelt * derating_value;
 document.getElementById("total_hours").innerHTML = total_hours_standby;
  }

 document.getElementById("total_hours").innerHTML = total_hours_standby;
```

```html
 <input type="number" id="panel" placeholder="panel quantity"></input><br>
 <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">Result</button>

 <p id="total_hours">result displays here</p>
```

Here I give you couple of ideas for improving it.

- Since you use global variable `total_hours_standby` it may be a good
  idea to encapsulate it. So called *module pattern* should do the job.
- New value of `total_hours_standby` does not seem to depend on an old
  one, so I guess you mean to use it somewhere else - in order to do
  so, you need to expose it with "public" getter.
- If above is not the case, then you don't need `total_hours_standby`
  variable at all and you can just directly return it or display it
  without storing this value in variable.
- I put code for rendering in separate function - this is because rule
  of thumb for functions is that they should have single
  responsibility. One functions for calculations, another for rendering
  and then one function for handling user's input and click event, that
  uses two previous ones. This way if for example you only want to
  calculate something without rendering result, then you just, simply can :)
- I also stored DOM nodes in variables, instead of calling
  getElementById, it is not due to performance, how it is often
  assumed, I did it only for better readability.
- Constants instead of hard-coded values.

```js
var Calculator = (function() {
  const panelInput = document.getElementById("panel");
  const output =  document.getElementById("total_hours");

  const PANEL_V = 65;
  const DERATING_VALUE = 2;
  
  const render = value => output.innerHTML = value;
  const calculate = value => value * PANEL_V * DERATING_VALUE;
  
  let total_hours_standby = 0;
  return {
    handleInput: function() {
      total_hours_standby = calculate(panelInput.value);
      render(total_hours_standby);
    },
    getTotalHoursStandby: () => total_hours_standby
  };
})();
```

```html
<input type="number" id="panel" placeholder="Panel quantity" />
 <button type="button" onclick="Calculator.handleInput()">Calculate</button>

 <p id="total_hours">Result displays here</p>
```

Comment: you have a `document.getElementById("total_hours").innerHTML = total_hours_standby;`  too many

Comment: You need one extra in order to display total_hours_standby when DOM content is loaded.

Comment: Then you can just call calculate and set value to 0 if empty

Comment: Sure you can, it will be NaN though based on OP's code and idea was to just fix it, not extending it by for example validating input. It is a simple snippet on SO, no need to review it like it's a pull request for super-duper feature of your enterprise app :D

Comment: What can I say other than "DRY"

Answer (score 0):

First, you should call method calculate.

```
<button type="button" onclick="calculate()">Result</button>
```

Then, add this line `document.getElementsById("total_hours").innerHTML = total_hours_standby;` inside calculate function.

Alos, typo error: document.getElementById instead of document.getElementsById

Answer (score -1):

It is typo,

document.getElement**s**ById

should be

document.getElementById

Comment: Please don't answer typo questions. There were 4 more issues

Comment: Thanks everyone, I am new to this and was told getElementsById in plural is correct. I corrected as follows to make it work: calculate() instead of only calculate,  getElementById in singular, move call for element within the function curly braces, remove ,parseInt‘. I have added further variables and calculations based on this and all is working. Thank you for your answers.